# Why is a single element list created like this in Scala Option?

Tags: scala

```
/** Returns a singleton list containing the $option's value
* if it is nonempty, or the empty list if the $option is empty.
*/  
def toList: List[A] =
  if (isEmpty) List() else new ::(this.get, Nil)
```

When they could have used

```
  if (isEmpty) List() else List(this.get)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're version (i.e. List(this.get)) is more readable and produces the same result, I'm willing to bet this is purely an optimization. That is, to get a non-empty list, the List constructor ("new ::") is going to have to be invoked at some point -- and the fastest way of getting there is calling it directly.

In the implementation of List.apply:

```
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

that constructor call is at least two extra stack frames away (List.apply, then xs.toList).

Comment: A bit strange that the empty case is `List()` instead of `Nil` in this case, same reasoning should apply.

Comment: There is a special case somewhere in the compiler that optimizes `List()` as `Nil`. That's why. But it's ugly, I agree.